# Need to trigger SQL Server stored procedure at beginning of ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

This is probably a simple question, but I need the act of running a report to have a "pre-event" of triggering a stored procedure. I am NOT returning data from the procedure, it is updating 2 tables in a data warehouse by doing a BULK INSERT from .csv files that have been exported from an ISAM database. The report itself uses a separate query to pull from the SQL Server tables, but the imported data is ultimately used by multiple reports so the tables need to be actually updated.

The stored procedure will run nightly as part of a regular routine, but the data affecting this particular report will be updated by users and a new .csv extract created immediately before running the report, so the report needs to fire the stored procedure to update the tables before it queries those tables itself.

I've tried searching but all the references I find seem to focus on using a stored procedure as the report query, and that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a separate query for pulling data, I need to run the stored procedure in-addition-to and preceding the report query, if that makes sense.

Does anybody know how to trigger a stored procedure as the opening line(s) of my report query?

Thanks in advance for any ideas. I'm not a SQL programmer (or any kind of programmer, really) so please be fairly specific with your advice... high-level concepts that assume any existing base of knowledge on my part will probably be lost on me.

This is the stored procedure (dbo.KCSI.DataUpdate) I wrote if that helps...

```
--To run as a script (query) the following 2 lines should be un-commented (there are 3 of these 'run-as-a-script' comments to find)
--USE KCSI
--Go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- To run as a script (query) the following 3 lines should all be commented out
CREATE PROCEDURE DataUpdate
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON 

-- Declare all the needed variables.
DECLARE @CustFile varchar(255)
DECLARE @CustFile_Exists int 
DECLARE @HistFile varchar(255)
DECLARE @HistFile_Exists int
DECLARE @dt varchar(30)
DECLARE @NewCustName varchar(250)
DECLARE @NewHistName varchar(250)

-- Sets Boolean value for whether or not each file exists, using T-SQL extended (i.e. DOS Shell) command
SELECT @CustFile='C:\transfer\ecallcust.csv' 
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist @CustFile, @CustFile_Exists OUT

SELECT @HistFile='C:\transfer\ecallhist.csv' 
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist @HistFile, @HistFile_Exists OUT

-- Sets a date variable to append to the final file name
SELECT @dt = REPLACE(Convert(varchar(30),getdate(),120),':','_')
-- Sets a variable to hold the final name. Variable use required because of the hybrid nature of the name (dos shell command + SQL variable)
SET @NewCustName = 'RENAME C:\transfer\history\ecallcust2.csv "ecallcust_'+@dt+'.csv"'
SET @NewHistName = 'RENAME C:\transfer\history\ecallhist2.csv "ecallhist_'+@dt+'.csv"'

-- Subroutine runs only if ecallcust.csv is present
IF @CustFile_Exists = 1
BEGIN

--Zaps the table
TRUNCATE TABLE custextract
-- Initially renames the file, using T-SQL extended (i.e. DOS Shell) command
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'RENAME C:\transfer\ecallcust.csv ecallcust2.csv'

-- Update table from CSV file
BULK INSERT custextract
FROM 'c:\transfer\ecallcust2.csv'
WITH (
ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
)

-- Move file to the history directory and rename it to include the date-time stamp using T-SQL extended (i.e. DOS Shell) command
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'MOVE C:\transfer\ecallcust2.csv C:\transfer\history\'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @NewCustName

END

-- Subroutine runs only if ecallhist.csv is present
IF @HistFile_Exists = 1
BEGIN

--Zaps the table
TRUNCATE TABLE histextract
-- Initially renames the file, using T-SQL extended (i.e. DOS Shell) command
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'RENAME C:\transfer\ecallhist.csv ecallhist2.csv'

-- Update table from CSV file
BULK INSERT histextract
FROM 'c:\transfer\ecallhist2.csv'
WITH (
ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
)

-- Move file to the history directory and rename it to include the date-time stamp using T-SQL extended (i.e. DOS Shell) command
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'MOVE C:\transfer\ecallhist2.csv C:\transfer\history\'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @NewHistName

END

-- To run as a script (query) the following line should be commented out
END
GO
```

and the report query...

```
WITH OrderedYTD AS
(
SELECT custextract.*, histextract.*,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY custextract.custcustno ORDER BY histextract.salesytd desc) AS RowNumber
FROM custextract 
INNER JOIN histextract 
    ON custextract.custcustno = histextract.histcustno
WHERE (custextract.ecall = 'Y')
) 

SELECT OrderedYTD.*
FROM OrderedYTD
WHERE RowNumber <= 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one stored procedure, that first updates the data and then returns the refreshed data to be loaded by the report...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DataSelect
AS
BEGIN

    -- Refresh Data Here
    EXEC DataUpdate

    -- Select Data for Report
    WITH OrderedYTD AS
    (
        SELECT custextract.*, histextract.*,
   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY custextract.custcustno ORDER BY histextract.salesytd desc) AS RowNumber
        FROM custextract 
        INNER JOIN histextract 
            ON custextract.custcustno = histextract.histcustno
        WHERE (custextract.ecall = 'Y')
    ) 

    SELECT OrderedYTD.*
    FROM OrderedYTD
    WHERE RowNumber <= 10;

END
```

Comment: Excellent! Then can I change my report to just use the stored procedure instead of the query it uses now? Will that force me to recreate the report? Sorry for all the questions but I'm normally a network tech suddenly forced into doing designer duty.  After this I still have to figure out how to modify it to accept an input parameter to be supplied from a web page for filtering by "store" and returning the finished report as a dynamic .pdf (not stored on disk) that pops up in their browser so they can print it locally. I've been pulling my hair out for 6 straight days so far...

Comment: Yes, you'll have to change the report to invoke the sp instead of the select, but as long as the new sp returns the same columns as the old select you won't have to do more changes... The other itens are should be easy enough to implment too, but if you get stuck then just create another question... :)

Comment: Thanks! Very concise and easily understood answers. I really appreciate the help!